# Downloadable MCQs on Mathematics

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-calculus, test-design

I am looking for multiple choice question (MCQ) based tests on some Mathematics' topics (details below), which could be downloaded in most preferably tex (LaTex) format or doc/docx format. Kindly please share any info on this if you have. Please do mention services or websites with payment as well.

I particularly need Linear Algebra and Multivariable Calculus (undergrad level) and basic Group Theory (undergrad level).

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As no-one answered yet... 
This doesn't fit the subjects you ask for, as it covers single variable calculus; but I really like the project.

Anyway: Cornell has a "[good questions](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~GoodQuestions/materials.html)" project. It is related to Stewarts calculus, but it is a good example of how one can get a good setting with useful questions.

so maybe someone knows similar projects for all kinds of classical undergrad math themes? Actually I guess there are many math departments at higher ed institutions maintaining their databases with MCQs for their service lectures. Understandable or not, they are reluctant to make them publicly available.